# What's the difference between .setPreferredInput(...) and .setPreferredDataSource(...)?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

What's the difference between `.setPreferredInput(_ inPort: AVAudioSessionPortDescription?)` and `.setPreferredDataSource(_ dataSource: AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription?)`?

Both functions can be used to determine the active or preferred microphone.

By calling:

```swift
import AVFoundation
let availableInputs = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs
```

I have an array containing built-in microphones, maybe an earphone microphone if connected, and so on. Each value in this array can be passed as a single argument to both functions. In the Data Source situation, you can pass it as an argument by calling `availableInputs![0].dataSources`, for example.

Is there any difference between them? How and when using they? `.setPreferredDataSource(...)` is more generic and can be called for input and output devices, but besides it, I can't see much difference between them.

I got an explanation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/OptimizingForDeviceHardware/OptimizingForDeviceHardware.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW1) in the documentation, but it doesn't help much:

> Setting a Preferred Input:
>
> To discover built-in or connected input
> ports, use the audio session’s availableInputs property. This property
> returns an array of AVAudioSessionPortDescription objects that
> describe the device’s available input ports. Ports can be identified
> by their portType property. To set a preferred input port (built-in
> microphone, wired microphone, USB input, and so on) use the audio
> session’s setPreferredInput:error: method.
>
> Setting a Preferred Data Source:
>
> Some ports, such as the built-in
> microphone and some USB accessories, support data sources. Apps can
> discover available data sources by querying the port description’s
> dataSources property. In the case of the built-in microphone, the
> returned data source description objects represent each individual
> microphone. Different devices return different values for the built-in
> mic. For instance, the iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S have two microphones:
> bottom and top. The iPhone 5 has three microphones: bottom, front, and
> back.
>
> Individual built-in microphones may be identified by a combination of
> a data source description’s location property (upper, lower) and
> orientation property (front, back, and so on). Apps may set a
> preferred data source by using the setPreferredDataSource:error:
> method of an AVAudioSessionPortDescription object.